# Generic Type Constraint does not seem to be constraining anything

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am having some issues surrounding the calling of a generic method.  In the example below, when I call `ServiceCar` from the base class I get an error when that method is defined in Dealer as:

Definition 1: `ServiceCar<C>(C carToService) where C : Car<C>`.

But I do not get an error in the base Class when that method is defined in Dealer as:

Definition 2: `ServiceCar<C>(Car<C> carToService) where C : Car<C>`

```
public abstract class Car<T> where T: Car<T>
{
     public bool isServiced;
     public string serviceMessage;

     public virtual void SendToService()
     {
          Dealer.ServiceCar<T>(this);       // error here when Definition 1 used
          serviceMessage = "Your car is clean.";
     }
 }

 public class Ford: Car<Ford>
 {
      public override void SendToService()
      {
           Dealer.ServiceCar<Ford>(this);
           serviceMessage = "Your Ford is clean.";
      }
 }

 public class Dealer
 {
      // When the parameter is defined as C (as commented below) an error occurs
      // When the parameter is defined as Car<C> there are no errors
      // public static void ServiceCar<C>(C carToService) where C : Car<C>
      public static void ServiceCar<C>(Car<C> carToService) where C : Car<C>
      {
           carToService.isServiced = true;
      }
 }
```

My confusion is that Microsoft [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) that "where T:  means the type argument must be or derive from the specified base class"  Well in the case of definition 1 (which does not compile) C is `Car<C>`.  So why isn't the type constraint parameter helping me out.  The error I am getting reads "...cannot convert from `Car<T>` to T"  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to call

```
public static void ServiceCar<C>(C carToService) where C : Car<C>
```

with this

```
Dealer.ServiceCar<T>(this);
```

you are passing an expression of type `Car<T>` to a method that wants an expression of type `T`. The reason it wants an expression of type `T` is because `Dealer.ServiceCar<T>` is explicitly defining the `C` as `T`, so the `carToService` parameter must be a `T`.

However, `Car<T>` is not convertable to `T`. Why should it be? It does not inherit from `T`. The only thing it inherits from is `object`. Therefore, the compiler cannot convert an expression of type `Car<T>` to an expression of type `T`, just as indicated.

To be clear, the documentation that you site and your class definition states that `T` must inherit from `Car<T>`, but it does not say the inverse, that `Car<T>` must inherit from `T`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you a confusing different type parameters. Class `Car<T>` has parameter `T` and method `ServiceCar<C>` has **another** type parameter `C`. So you need to specify both type parameters in the method and class declaration:

```
ServiceCar<C, T>(C carToService) where C : Car<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

Off hand it looks like your confusing generics and inheritance. Keep in mind what other developers might have to do when they inherit your code. I always opt for simplicity when possible.

```
public abstract class Car
{
     public bool isServiced;
     public string serviceMessage;

     public abstract string TypeName { get; }
     public virtual void SendToService()
     {
          Dealer.ServiceCar(this);       // error here when Definition 1 used
          servicesMessage = string.Format("Your {0} is clean.", Car.TypeName);
     }
 }

 public class Ford: Car
 {
      public override string TypeName { get { return "Ford"; } }
      //No need to override this because Ford inherits from Car
      //public override void SendToService()
      //{
      //     Dealer.ServiceCar<Ford>(this);
      //     serviceMessage = "Your Ford is clean.";
      //}
 }

 public class Dealer
 {

      public static void ServiceCar(Car carToService)
      {
           carToService.isServiced = true;
      }
 }
```

Comment: I know this wasn't an ideal sample and there are better ways to do it.  I was just trying to find a way to call the same generic method from both a base class and an inherited class.

Comment: Oh, ok. You can try this then `public static void ServiceCar<C>(C carToService) where C : Car` And remove the generics definition from your base class.

Answer (score 0):

In definition 1, `Dealer.ServiceCar<T>` takes a parameter of type `T`. You are passing `this` into the method, which is of type `Car<T>`. How are you going to convert `Car<T>` to `T`? The `where` constraint only says `T` is a `Car<T>`, but not the other way around.